# Literal URL in dynamically-generated SVG prohibited?

Tags: javascript, url, svg, encodeuricomponent

I'm generating an SVG dynamically in javascript, which works fine. When I try to include the current location.href as a literal string within the image's text content (eg: "Source: http://www.google.com"), it fails. When I use `encodeURIComponent(location.href)` it works again (`encodeURI(location.href)` does not), but the url is ugly/less readable.

I'm guessing SVG prohibits the inclusion of literal URLs?

How does one display the generating page's location.href as a non-encoded URL? I was trying to find the equivalent of a JSON.stringify function so that the SVG generator doesn't interpret it as a URL.

Comment: SVG is XML, when you output it it must be valid XML see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents

Comment: Strangely, the quote and apostrophe weren't preventing the svg from rendering even though they're present; only the & was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those facing the same problem, I discovered that rendering any TEXT--page content or URL--as an SVG, you must replace all instances of `&` with the ASCII equivalent `&amp;`. This may mean you have to filter for ASCII characters, because the resulting output will be the literal ASCII code, eg: "`blah blah Meat &amp; Potatoes blah blah`".